# In mySQL, how do I get and set a value in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the highest Line Order number in the table, set it to a variable, increment it, then insert it with new data as a new record.
The script is in PHP and $SQL is for mySQL

```
$SQL="  
      BEGIN
        DECLARE lineOrder INT DEFAULT 1;
        SET lineOrder = (
           SELECT IFNULL(`Line Order`,1)
           FROM `router`
           ORDER BY `Line Order` DESC
           lIMIT 1);
        lineOrder = lineOrder + 1;
        INSERT INTO `router`(`Line Order`, `Estimated Time`,
                               `Estimated Time Unit`, `Work Center`,
                               `Work Description`)
        VALUES (lineOrder,?,?,?,?);
      END;
    ";
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mySQLConnection']->prepare($SQL);
echo $GLOBALS['mySQLConnection']->error;
```

This is the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET lineOrder = (SELECT IFNULL(`Line Order`,1) FROM `router` ' at line 2

Comment: why not just use an auto_increment ID?

Comment: Because the user has to be able to create an order of the records in my UI

Comment: @serv92 put a new column called order and let him/her/it use that one for order -.-

Comment: You can select the max value of a field and then doing +1, without declare

Comment: For indexing I have RN and Line Order. RN is primary and is set to auto increment. Line Order is just for the user to put records in any order they want, it is set as a unique column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `router` (`Line Order`,
     `Estimated Time`, `Estimated Time Unit`, `Work Center`, `Work Description`)
SELECT 1 + IFNULL(MAX(`Line Order`), 0),
     ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM `router`
```

Comment: what version? I'm using 4.2.7

Comment: Oops I'm actually using 5.6.2 I get 0 rows inserted. with no errors. 4.2.7 is my phpMyAdmin version

Comment: Hmm... my query has a flaw: it does not work when the table `router` is empty :-(

Comment: Fixed the query in the answer. No more `ORDER BY`, no more `LIMIT`. It works with empty `router` table too.